# Collapsed Bootstrap 3 Navbar goes out of bounds (dropdowns)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have a normal Bootstrap 3 fixed navbar in the top of my website which is really nice. The problem I'm facing and discovered the other day was that when the navbar collapses for being accessible in smaller devices, the dropdown items are going off the area designated for the navbar. The picture below explains it best:

[image: Problem]

So, the *Dugi* part is a dropdown menu item. When clicked, the items under it (marked in red) are going beyond the red part of the menu. Isn't the navbar supposed to go down with them and cover up the space?

Anyway, I've obviously touched the navbar's styling and I guess that's where it's going wrong. Here's what I've touched:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: @dry-red;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @dry-red, @mid-red);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @dry-red, @mid-red);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(@dry-red), to(@mid-red));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @dry-red, @mid-red);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, @dry-red, @mid-red);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, @dry-red, @mid-red);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@dry-red', endColorstr='@mid-red', GradientType=0);
    border-color: @dark-red;
    overflow: visible;
    max-height: 51px;

    @media (max-width: 768px){
        max-height: none;
        height: auto;
    }

    @media (max-width: 470px){
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    max-height: 51px;

    @media (max-width: 768px){
        max-height: none;
    }
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: @lighten;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: @lighten-hover;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: @lighten;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: @lighten-hover;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: @lighten;
    background-color: @dark-red;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: @lighten-hover;
    background-color: @dark-red;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
    border-top-color: @dark-red;
    border-bottom-color: @dark-red;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: @dark-red;
    border-bottom-color: @dark-red;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: @dark-red;
    border-bottom-color: @dark-red;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: @dark-red;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: @dark-red;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: @lighten;
}

.nav > .dropdown, .dropdown-menu > li {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}

.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: @lighten;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color: @lighten-hover;
    }
}

.dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  right: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  right: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}

.nav-center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 91px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -45px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.navbar-inner {
    position: relative;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<nav class="website-nav navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="nav-center">
            <!-- <img src="{{ S_WEB_PATH }}images/brand.png" /> -->
            <div class="nav-brand"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="alt-nav navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toogle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div><!-- Navigation header -->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li {{ INDEX_ACTIVE }}><a href="home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Home</a></li>
            <li {{ REMOTE_ACTIVE }}><a href="remote"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Remote</a></li>
            <li {{ ZIP_ACTIVE }} class="visible-lg"><a href="zip"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> ZIP</a></li>
            <li {{ POPULAR_ACTIVE }}><a href="popular"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Popular</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            {% if not S_LOGGED_IN %}
            <li><a href="#register" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></span> Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#login" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge user-messages">0</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge user-notification">0</span></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle valign-middle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>&nbsp; My Images</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">All images</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Album 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Album 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    {% if S_SERVICE_USED == 'facebook' %}
                        <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{ S_USERNAME }}/picture" height="24px" class="img-circle avatar" alt="Avatar">
                    {% else %}
                        {% if S_USER_AVATAR != '' %}<img src="{{ S_AVATAR_PATH }}" id="my_avatar" height="24px" class="img-circle avatar" alt="Avatar">{% else %}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>{% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                    &nbsp;<span class="{% if S_SERVICE_USED == 'facebook' or S_USER_AVATAR != '' %}valign-middle{% endif %}">{{ S_USERNAME }}</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="{{ S_WEB_PATH }}user/{{ S_USERNAME }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Settings</a></li>
                    {% if S_SERVICE_USED != 'facebook' and S_SERVICE_USED != 'twitter' %}<li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit Profile</a></li>{% endif %}
                    <li><a href="{{ S_WEB_PATH }}user/do/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            {% endif %} 
        </ul>   
    </div>
</nav><!-- Navigation -->
```

Anything other than this, there is nothing I've touched. I've tried fixing this in the `.navbar-default` by adding this in it:

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    max-height: none;
    height: auto;
}
```

This didn't do anything.

Any help would be highly appreciated as it's really irritating to see this happening and having no clue where it's coming from. Could this be Bootstrap's problem? I doubt it.

Comment: Ref: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12006 (maybe you opened it?)

Comment: Please add jsFiddle for this.

Comment: This is another issue. The link at GitHub is irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the `.navbar-default` max-height that causes the scroll.  It's the `.navbar-collapse`.

Without adding any of your styles and just using Bootstrap's default, I can see that scrollbar and it's caused by this:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  max-height: 340px;  /* *** THIS IS YOUR ISSUE *** */
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.navbar-collapse.in {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

**[A demo of the scrollbar showing.](http://jsbin.com/iDuNACoL/1/edit)**

So you can fix that by overriding that in your styles:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  max-height: none; 
}
```

**[A demo with scrollbar gone.](http://jsbin.com/iDuNACoL/2/edit)**

Finally, with regard to your avatar being too big on the larger screens, if you really want to use your media query you'd do it like this:

```
.navbar-default {
  max-height: 51px; 
}

.navbar-collapse {
  max-height: none; 
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
  .navbar-default {
    max-height: none;
  }
}
```

**[A demo of media query working.](http://jsbin.com/iDuNACoL/3/edit)**

Although to be honest with the last example I'm not sure why you don't just set a [max-height on the avatar like this](http://jsbin.com/iDuNACoL/4/edit).

Comment: that hasn't worked for me.  I find the the navbar works fine when the device is vertical but not horizontal.

Comment: @totneschap - It works in the demo on a wider screen, what issue are you specifically having?

Comment: @davidpauljunior - When you flip a phone to horizontal, the very bottom two items on the dropdown are not visible. The solutions that you have provided are not working for me, any ideas?

Comment: @totneschap - not visible because they're off the screen?  I've just tested this on a horizontal iPhone5 and I just have to scroll (swipe) like normal to see the rest of the menu.

Comment: @davidpauljunior - yes, because they're off the screen, I just can't continue scrolling to be able to get to them. So if i change .navbar-collapse {max-height: 340px;} to .navbar-collapse {max-height: none;}, that should work? Cheers for trying to help me by the way, really appreciate it.

Comment: @totneschap - As the code provided here works on the device horizontally, you need to open up a new question (maybe reference this one) and show your code, which may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting max-height: auto, just take out the max-height: 51px; styles and leave it at height: auto.  The container should expand to fit your content.

Comment: I have added that part because the avatar (the profile image) increases the height of the navbar completely, making it look kind of bad. Is that the only solution?

Comment: I'm confused now.  Are you wanting the height of the navbar's container to grow to fit all of your menu items?  If so, then setting the height of that container to auto is the easiest way to ensure that it's big enough to show everything.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. When the navbar is in large and medium, it wont collapse. And then, the profile image will cause the navbar to increase its height and look kinda weird. I got it fixed by adding that `max-height` property. However, when the navbar collapses, the navbar becomes like in the picture above. So in either case, it's becoming quite hard to handle. This is how it looks like without the adding `max-height` in an uncollapsed mode: http://i.imgur.com/jqxGntz.png **AND** the problem still exists, the collapsed version is still glitched.

Comment: I think I might see the problem, but I still have some question before I edit my answer.  Join me in chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45012/collapsed-bootstrap-3-navbar-goes-out-of-bounds-dropdowns

Comment: I was in the chat room, but you weren't responding